# use htmlunit how to get modal dialog element

Tags: modal-dialog, web-crawler, htmlunit

I want to go to the website https://console.mobra.in by htmlunit tool, but login input in the modal box, how to get username input element or login form?

Answer (score 0):

Use the queryselector method in HTMLUNIT.

```
usernamebox = currentPage.querySelector("[placeholder='username or email address']");
passwordbox = currentPage.querySelector("[data-ng-model='user.password']");
```

To get the above CSS selector, you may install chrome extension 'CSS Selector' of using the [selectorgadget](http://selectorgadget.com/).

If it works, please tick it as answer, or otherwise please leave a comment below.